# Trouble putting together a query with multiple conditions

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that checks for stock levels. I need to filter the items based on the CustomerID variable provided in the software. There isn't a direct join between Items and Customers. I do however have custom fields in the Customers which defines what groups of Items they are allowed to purchase from (Boolean). I also have a custom field in the Item that determines what group it belongs to (string).

I tried using a Cross Join, but as you can image, I got blank items and data to the right, which I did not want. I don't have the rest of (stock check) query, at this point I am trying to get the Items to show for the Customer based on the groups. I have replaced the actual fields with Group1, Group2, etc. Please ignore the brackets.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerNo,
       Customers.CustomerID,
       Customers.Name,
       CASE
           WHEN Customers.[Group1] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group1'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.Group2 = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group2'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group3] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group3'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group4] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group4'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.Group5 = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group5'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group6] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group6'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group7] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group7'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group8] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group8'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.[Group9] = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group9'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.Group10 = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group10'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           WHEN Customers.Group11 = 1
                AND Items.UserDefined1 = 'Group11'
           THEN Items.ItemNo
           ELSE ''
       END AS ItemNo,
       Items.Name AS Description,
       Items.UserDefined1
FROM
(
    SELECT Items_1.ItemNo,
           Items_1.Name,
           ItemsUserDefined.UserDefined1
    FROM dbo.Items AS Items_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined1,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo
    WHERE(ModuleID = 12)
) AS ItemsUserDefined ON Items_1.ItemID = ItemsUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Items
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT Customers_1.CustomerNo,
           Customers_1.Name,
           Customers_1.CustomerID,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group1],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group2,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group3],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group4],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group5,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group6],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group7],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group8],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group9],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group10,
           CustomerUserDefined.Group11
    FROM dbo.Customers AS Customers_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined9 AS [Group1],
           UserDefined10 AS Group2,
           UserDefined11 AS [Group3],
           UserDefined12 AS [Group4],
           UserDefined13 AS Group5,
           UserDefined14 AS [Group6],
           UserDefined15 AS [Group7],
           UserDefined16 AS [Group8],
           UserDefined17 AS [Group9],
           UserDefined18 AS Group10,
           UserDefined20 AS Group11,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo AS AdditionalInfo_1
    WHERE(ModuleID = 38)
) AS CustomerUserDefined ON Customers_1.CustomerID = CustomerUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Customers
WHERE CustomerID = 472
```

Answer (score 0):

I have joined the customer and items table using case statement since there is no direct link between these two tables.

**Query**

```
select items.name,customers.customerID, items.userdefined1
from customers
inner join Items on items.userdefined1 = (case when customers.group1 =1 then 'group1' 
                                               when customers.group2 =1 then 'group2' 
                                               when customers.group3 =1 then 'group3' 
                                               when customers.group4 =1 then 'group4' 
                                               when customers.group5 =1 then 'group5' 
                                          end )
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out where to fit that in, but I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the case statement is not correct, it stops parsing after it finds the first match.

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: see the modified query

Answer (score 0):

So SQL is going to stop parsing when it finds the first 'TRUE' of the expression. I need it to return ALL that are true.

```
SELECT CustomerNo,
       CustomerID,
       Items.ItemNo,
       Items.Name AS Description
FROM
(
    SELECT Customers_1.CustomerNo,
           Customers_1.Name,
           Customers_1.CustomerID,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group1],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group2,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group3],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group4],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group5,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group6],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group7],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group8],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group9],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group10,
           CustomerUserDefined.Group11
    FROM dbo.Customers AS Customers_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined9 AS [Group1],
           UserDefined10 AS Group2,
           UserDefined11 AS [Group3],
           UserDefined12 AS [Group4],
           UserDefined13 AS Group5,
           UserDefined14 AS [Group6],
           UserDefined15 AS [Group7],
           UserDefined16 AS [Group8],
           UserDefined17 AS [Group9],
           UserDefined18 AS Group10,
           UserDefined20 AS Group11,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo AS AdditionalInfo_1
    WHERE(ModuleID = 38)
) AS CustomerUserDefined ON Customers_1.CustomerID = CustomerUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Customers
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Items_1.ItemNo,
           Items_1.Name,
           ItemsUserDefined.UserDefined1
    FROM dbo.Items AS Items_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined1,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo
    WHERE(ModuleID = 12)
) AS ItemsUserDefined ON Items_1.ItemID = ItemsUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Items ON Items.UserDefined1 = (CASE
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group1] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group1'
                                        WHEN Customers.Group2 = 1
                                        THEN 'Group2'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group3] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group3'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group4] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group4'
                                        WHEN Customers.Group5 = 1
                                        THEN 'Group5'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group6] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group6'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group7] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group7'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group8] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group8'
                                        WHEN Customers.[Group9] = 1
                                        THEN 'Group9'
                                        WHEN Customers.Group10 = 1
                                        THEN 'Group10'
                                        WHEN Customers.Group11 = 1
                                        THEN 'Group11'
                                    END)
WHERE CustomerID = 578;
```

Answer (score 0):

In below example, customer 124 are having two true record for group3. Case statement returns both the records.

```
    select items.name,customers.customerID, items.userdefined1
from customers
inner join Items on items.userdefined1 = (case when customers.group1 =1 then 'group1' 
                                               when customers.group2 =1 then 'group2' 
                                               when customers.group3 =1 then 'group3' 
                                               when customers.group4 =1 then 'group4' 
                                               when customers.group5 =1 then 'group5' 
                                          end )
```

[image]

I have Modified the below query. Instead of directly using case statement I have used it as subquery to fetch `Items.UserDefined1`. Couldn't run the query since i don't have  table `AdditionalInfo`.

Try this,

```
SELECT CustomerNo,
       CustomerID,
       Items.ItemNo,
       Items.Name AS Description
FROM
(
    SELECT Customers_1.CustomerNo,
           Customers_1.Name,
           Customers_1.CustomerID,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group1],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group2,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group3],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group4],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group5,
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group6],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group7],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group8],
           CustomerUserDefined.[Group9],
           CustomerUserDefined.Group10,
           CustomerUserDefined.Group11
    FROM dbo.Customers AS Customers_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined9 AS [Group1],
           UserDefined10 AS Group2,
           UserDefined11 AS [Group3],
           UserDefined12 AS [Group4],
           UserDefined13 AS Group5,
           UserDefined14 AS [Group6],
           UserDefined15 AS [Group7],
           UserDefined16 AS [Group8],
           UserDefined17 AS [Group9],
           UserDefined18 AS Group10,
           UserDefined20 AS Group11,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo AS AdditionalInfo_1
    WHERE(ModuleID = 38)
) AS CustomerUserDefined ON Customers_1.CustomerID = CustomerUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Customers
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Items_1.ItemNo,
           Items_1.Name,
           ItemsUserDefined.UserDefined1
    FROM dbo.Items AS Items_1
         INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserDefined1,
           OwnerID
    FROM dbo.AdditionalInfo
    WHERE(ModuleID = 12)
) AS ItemsUserDefined ON Items_1.ItemID = ItemsUserDefined.OwnerID
) AS Items ON Items.UserDefined1 in(select items.userdefined1
                                    from customers
                                    inner join Items on items.userdefined1 = (case when customers.group1 =1 then 'group1' 
                                                                                   when customers.group2 =1 then 'group2' 
                                                                                   when customers.group3 =1 then 'group3' 
                                                                                   when customers.group4 =1 then 'group4' 
                                                                                   when customers.group5 =1 then 'group5' 
                                                                             end ))
WHERE CustomerID = 578;
```